# Changing "if" python statement to apply to any obstacle instead of specific obstacles

Tags: python, if-statement

(Disclaimer: I'm very new to coding so sorry if this is a ridiculously stupid question!)

I'm currently trying to change the Python code below so that instead of needing 4 obstacles to not be false in order to call the obstacle_detection method (which is defined earlier in the program), it will call the method if any number of obstacles are not False.

```
if obstacle is not False and obstacle2 is not False and obstacle3 is not False and obstacle4 is not False:
    test = obstacle_detection(obstacle, pos)
    test2 = obstacle_detection(obstacle2, pos)
    test3 = obstacle_detection(obstacle3, pos)
    test4 = obstacle_detection(obstacle4, pos)

else:
    test = 0
    test2 = 0
    test3 = 0
    test4 = 0
```

I the tried changing it to something like below but I get the error of "iteration over non sequence" (and I wouldn't be surprised if this is completely the wrong idea):

```
if any(obstacle) is not False:
    for i in obstacle:
        test = obstacle_detection(obstacle, pos)

else:
    test = 0
```

Comment: Can you put your obstacles in a list instead of having them in separate variables?

Comment: You've not included the definition of obstacle (or obstacle2 or obstacle3 or ...). You also don't need to identity compare to True or False. Use the truth value of the values directly.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you put your `obstacle` variables in a list.

```
obstacles = [obstacle, obstacle1, obstacle2, obstacle3]
```

If I read you right, for any of these that not `False` (though this is a pretty odd way to be using `False`), you want to call `obstacle_detection`, and assign the result to a `test` variable.

```
tests = []
for obstacle in obstacles:
    if obstacle:
        tests.append(obstacle_detection(obstacle, pos))
    else:
        tests.append(0)
```

Or more succinctly:

```
tests = [obstacle_detection(obstacle, pos) if obstacle else 0 for obstacle in obstacles]
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments this will work

```
if obstacle and obstacle2 and obstacle3 and obstacle4:
```

Also python has an `any` and `all` operater that can be used on any sequence (`lists`, `tuples`, `dict`)

let's say you have a list filled with obstacles like this `obstacle_list = [True, True, True, True]` then the above statement can be rewritten like this

```
if all(obstacle_list):
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all your obstacles to be `True` use `all()`:

```
obstacles = [obstacle1, obstacle2, obstacle3, obstacle4]
evaluate = all(obstacles)
for index, obstacle in enumerate(obstacles)
    locals()["test{}".format(index+1)] = obstacle_detection(obstacle, pos) if evaluate else 0
```

If you really don't want to define your obstacle list upfront (bad design, but...) you can pick them up automatically:

```
obstacles = [globals()[x] for x in globals() if x.startswith("obstacle")]
```

But keep in mind that you might get clashes that way so make sure all your `obstacle` variables have a number following them. Also, this addresses only the global scope, you can use `local()` for the local scope.

If you really want to do it with no change to your variables whatsoever, you can do it as:

```
all_obstacles = {x[8:]: globals()[x] for x in globals() if x.startswith("obstacle")}
evaluate = all(all_obstacles.values())
for k, v in all_obstacles.items():
    globals()["test{}".format(k)] = obstacle_detection(v, pos) if evaluate else 0
```

This will produce a `test<x>` variable for every `obstacle<x>` variable in the global space (including `test` for `obstacle`) and either evaluate it through the `obstacle_detection()` function or set it to `0` if all of the `obstacles` don't evaluate to `True`.

Comment: I get this error: dictionary changed size during iteration, for this line:  obstacles = [locals()[x] for x in locals() if x.startswith("obstacle")]

Comment: Change the name of `obstacles` to something else (e.g. `all_obstacles`), in case something is changing the global namespace in your `obstacle_detection` function. Either way, this is a really, really bad design - better define your obstacles as finite structures within a `list` or `dict` so you don't rely on the rest of the code not changing the script state.

Comment: The reason for not wanting to define the different obstacles because the number of obstacles changes each time I create a new environment to run the test in... All I'm wanting is for the obstacle_detection to be called any time an obstacle is not false

Comment: @AnnaS - and what creates those 'obstacles'? If you're creating them, you can also keep them in a tidy, controlled list. Also, judging by your starting code and explanation, you want to call obstacle detection on all obstacles when **all** of them are not evaluating to `False`, not when just one of them isn't - if you want it to be called if any of them is not `False` use `any()` instead of `all()` in the last example above (e.g. `evaluate = any(all_obstacles.values())`).

Answer (score 0):

try to put obstacle variables into array

```
obstacle_item=[obstacle,obstacle2,obstacle3,obstacle4]
test = 0

if any(obstacle_item) is not False:
    #call obstacle detection function
    for item in obstacle_item:
        test = obstacle_detection(obstacle_item,pos)

print test
```